# java classpath is finding a library unexpectedly

Tags: java, classpath, glob

Suppose any trivial use of `joda` such as

```
package com.domain.testPackage;
public class MyObject
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println((new org.joda.time.DateTime()).toString());
    }
}
```

The `jar` can be exported from Eclipse (Neon) via

`File>Export>Java/Runnable Jar>Next>"Copy required libraries into a sub-folder"`

Both of the following invocations of `java` will run.

`java -cp testProject.jar:testProject_lib/'*' com.domain.testPackage.MyObject`

`java -cp testProject.jar com.domain.testPackage.MyObject`

It seems that only the first run is correct. Why does the second invocation run?

BTW: Note the `java` wildcard * should be quoted so that Linux does not expand the wildcard. Instead the wildcard is passed verbatim to `java` and takes the Java-specific meaning that is "all the JAR files". Note that it also works without the quotes. I said you should quote it, not that you need to. It works because Linux glob is unlikely to find a file name that, among other specifics, has a colon in the middle like this `testProject.jar:testProject_lib/*` and a side-effect of making zero matches is that glob will conveniently (or bizarrely?) echo the whole token and `java` will see the echoed token and interpret it in Java-fashion.

Comment: did you specify the main-class in the manifest of the jar file?

Comment: I do not explicitly create manifests; I just use Eclipse "export" in the manner described. However, I will look around to investigate.

Comment: The manifest includes this: `Class-Path: . testProject_lib/joda-time-2.9.2.jar` which was unexpected but nice I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class-Path: . testProject_lib/joda-time-2.9.2.jar`

That was found in the manifest. That explains it.